# Make clang-format keep control statements line breaks

Tags: c++, clang-format

We have specific coding rules that specify that there should be a line break between the control statement keyword (`if`, `while`, `for`, ...) and the condition inside. Is there any way I can reproduce that rule using clang-format ?

Example code:

```
if
    (myCondition)
{
    // Do stuff
}

while
    (   myVeryLongCondition
    AND myOtherVeryLongCondition
    OR  myAlternativeCondition)
{
    // Do other stuff
}
```

P.S.: We use tabs for indentation, if that makes any difference

Comment: I looked through every option, and I couldn't find any, which would have surprised me anyways since that is such an uncommon style. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I do agree, I did the same and arrived to the same conclusion, that's  why I asked the question, in case I missed something.